# Pattern-matching Function with conditions on arbitrary number of arguments

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching

I'm trying to add a long list of pattern matching conditions to an existing function, which takes a variable number of arguments.

I know there are similar threads on this topic, but I was unable to make them work for the particular example I'd like to do.

Take the condition that says numerical objects should be factored out of the function argument.

```
lol[c_?NumericQ d_] := c lol[d]

lol[2]
lol[2 kk]

(* -> lol[2] *)
(* -> 2 lol[kk] *)
```

Now I would like it to be able to apply this condition to an arbitrary number of slots. For example I would like to write something like

```
lol[c_?NumericQ d__] := c lol[d]

lol[2]
lol[2 kk]
lol[2 kk, 3 jj]

(* -> lol[2] *)
(* -> 2 lol[kk] *)
(* -> 6 lol[kk,jj] *)
```

but instead

```
lol[2 kk, 3 jj]
```

simply returns

```
(* -> lol[2 kk, 3 jj] *)
```

Just to emphasise: it must be able to handle any number of inputs, I can't just code rules for 2 slots in addition to the rule for 1 slot. And the goal is to be able to update the properties of "lol" as a function, not just to produce a procedure that can factor Numeric objects out of functions (because I have an existing function that needs to have these properties but is too lengthy to paste her).

Comment: This looks to be a problem where both the input and output arguments of `lol` should be lists.  You may then also want to consider ReplaceAll.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I'll be able to use ReplaceAll to update the properties of an existing function... will give it a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

```
lol[left___, c_?NumericQ d_, right___] := c lol[left, d, right]
```

Comment: Can this approach handle the case of multiple slots with numerical multipliers as requested in the question?

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, it can.

Comment: Confirmed, works perfectly on any number of slots. 
@QuantumDot Can you explain why it works? I've tried to think through what procedure Mathematica follows with the case of 1, 2, or 3 slots, but I'm lost.

Comment: @JonRayner `___` is [`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) and represents any number of arguments.  When the pattern matcher encounters this in a pattern, it tries all possible combinations to match the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I've got

```
lol[x : (PatternSequence[_?NumericQ _Symbol] ..)] :=
    (Times @@ {x}[[All, 1]]) lol[Sequence @@ {x}[[All, 2]]]
```

which gives

```
lol[2 k, 3 j]
```

> 6 lol[k, j]

```
lol[2 k, 3 j, 5 m]
```

> 30 lol[k, j, m]

---

Caveats:

```
lol[2 k, j]
```

> lol[2 k, j]

```
lol[2 k, 1 j]
```

> lol[2 k, j]

but

```
lol[2 k, 1. j]
```

> 2. lol[k, j]

Also

```
lol[2 k, 7]
```

> lol[2 k, 7]

but I'm not sure what should the function do in this case.

---

**And a brute one:**

```
Clear[lol]
lol[x__] := 
 Module[{y = List@x, coeffs, vars, c}, 
  vars = Variables /@ y // Flatten; 
  coeffs = Coefficient[##] & @@@ Transpose@{y, vars}; 
  c = Times @@ coeffs; c Defer@lol[##] & @@ vars]


lol[2 k, j]
```

> 2 lol[k, j]